# What kind of compiler optimizations happen for cpp vars when volatile keyword is not used?

Tags: c++, compilation, volatile

I was reading about the `volatile` keyword in c++ and tried this sample piece of code which gave the result as follows:

[image: sample code block]

When I added the volatile keyword to the const var declaration the output became 200 for both vars. Can someone explain what kind of var optimizations the compiler might've done here? Thanks!

Comment: Modifying a const object results in _undefined behavior_.

Comment: Also, don't paste images of code. Always paste the code as text instead, such as others may copy it.

Comment: I expected the same. But when I added volatile it was working very well. I couldn't understand how it worked in the background.

Comment: Study the generated assembly if you want to explain undefined behavior.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I somehow managed to miss this in all the open tabs I have.

Comment: BTW, note that `volatile` very very rarely make sense together with `const`. The latter basically says that the object **is immutable** while the former that it **may be mutated** at any time from outside by some external mechanism, which is in contradiction.

Comment: @DanielLangr: read-only and immutability are different though (The later implies the former). and volatile read-only might make sense.